# selenium webdriver python finding elements with out id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to selenium python, How to select username field and password field to automate the login page.
the id is not given for both fields.
this is the source code.

```
<div class='tablecss'>   
<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='0' align='center'> <tr 
id='usernamelbl'><td style='color:#565656;text-align:left;'>
<label >Username</label></td></tr><tr id='usernametxt'>
<td><input type='text' name='username' maxlength='50' class='textbox' >
</td></tr>
<tr id='passwordlbl'><td style='color:#565656;text-align:left;'>
<label>Password</label></td></tr><tr><td>
<input type='password' name='password' autocomplete='off' 
class='textbox'>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type='submit' name='btnSubmit' value='Login' id='logincaption' 
class='button' style='color:#565656' /></td></tr></table></div>
```

Below is the code that I use to select the elements:

```
user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#txtUserName')
user.send_keys('pv13')
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#txtPassword')
password.send_keys('9979173')
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have done it here, it won't work as there is no ID 'txtUserName' or 'txtPassword'.

If you want to select the input for the username and password, you could simply do it by xpath.

For example:

```
user_name_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="username"]')
user_name_input.send_keys('pv13')
password_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//input[@name="password"]')
password_input.send_keys('9979173')
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: @user124384, why did you downvote my answer? Can you give me an explanation or show me your code? This should work to insert a user name and password into these inputs

Comment: Because, as I said, it didn't work for me. Although perhaps it might work in some situations, in my case it incomplete. It was sufficient to use `find_elements_by_name`, and I also needed to throw in a `sleep(7)` in order for the page to load first.

Comment: Yeah, you needed to add a delay because the page needed time to load. This is a problem with the page itself, not the code.